# How to implement max heap with pair using priority queue in java?

Tags: java, heap, priority-queue

I am trying to implement Max heap with key value pair in java. As we know in C++ we can do that in this way..

```
    priority_queue<pair<int, int> > pq;
    pq.push(make_pair(10, 200));
    pq.push(make_pair(20, 100));
    pq.push(make_pair(15, 400));
```

But I am unable to do this in java, please help me to do so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java. Is it possible to use a pair in a priority queue and then return a value using the key as a priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61702224/java-is-it-possible-to-use-a-pair-in-a-priority-queue-and-then-return-a-value-u)

Comment: You can not use the [Priority Key](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) with a pair.

If you want so, will need to write some code.

Comment: Note that answers suggesting PriorityQueue do not address your question since you are asking for a heap implementation. That behind the scenes this priority queue is implemented using a binary heap is just a technical detail.

Answer (score 2):

There is a discussion with examples [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/priority-queue-of-pair-in-java-with-examples/).

Briefly, you can set up the queue by providing key value pairs and specifying how pairs should be compared:

```
PriorityQueue<Pair<Integer,Integer>> pq = 
    new PriorityQueue<>((a,b)-> b.getValue() - a.getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Java` you can use a `HashMap` for that:

```
import javafx.util.Pair;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class YourClass{

    public static void main (String[] args){

        int n = 3;

PriorityQueue<Pair<Integer,Integer> > pq = new PriorityQueue<Pair<Integer,Integer>>(n, Comparator.comparing(Pair::getKey));

  /*Adding elements to HashMap*/
  pq.add(new Pair <> (10, 200));
  pq.add(new Pair <> (20, 100));
  pq.add(new Pair <> (15, 400));

 System.out.println(l.poll().getValue()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no method like `poll` in hash map. You will need to know the key in order to get an element.

Comment: I am sorry, actually I have found this type of code but couldn't understand properly. It will be very grateful if you explain these as well!

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand. Is Pair a hashmap, it is different right? Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

The Pair can be used for this use case which is from the `javafx.util` package.

If we need to sort it based on the value.

```java
import javafx.util.Pair;
import java.util.*;

public class ExampleClass {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
          PriorityQueue<Pair<Integer, Integer>> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>((num1, num2) -> Integer.compare(num2.getValue(), num1.getValue()));
          maxHeap.offer(new Pair<>(10, 200));
          maxHeap.offer(new Pair<>(20, 100));
          maxHeap.offer(new Pair<>(15, 400));
    }
}
```

If we need to sort it based on the key.

```java
import javafx.util.Pair;
import java.util.*;

public class ExampleClass {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
          PriorityQueue<Pair<Integer, Integer>> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>((num1, num2) -> Integer.compare(num2.getKey(), num1.getKey()));
          maxHeap.offer(new Pair<>(10, 200));
          maxHeap.offer(new Pair<>(20, 100));
          maxHeap.offer(new Pair<>(15, 400));
    }
}
```

Here we are creating an instance of the priority queue by passing a simple [lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) expression as a constructor parameter.

We can print the result using a while loop to check whether the `maxHeap` is empty or non-empty.

```java
while (!maxHeap.isEmpty()) {
     Pair<Integer, Integer> topOfHeap = maxHeap.poll();
     System.out.println(topOfHeap.getValue());
}
```